# When do Template.currentData() and template.data differ in value?

Tags: meteor

I know one is a reactive source, while the other is not. But I thought they would always give the same value.

Then I found the following code in Telescope's source:

```
    var newTerms = Template.currentData().terms; // ⚡ reactive ⚡
    if (!_.isEqual(newTerms, instance.data.terms)) {
      instance.postsLimit.set(instance.data.terms.limit || Settings.get('postsPerPage', 10));
    }
```

link: https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/telescope-posts/lib/client/templates/posts_list/posts_list_controller.js#L33

So it seems these two values can sometimes differ. When?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Meteor's documentation, about [`template.data`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_data):

> This property provides access to the data context at the top level of
>   the template. **It is updated each time the template is re-rendered.**
>   Access is read-only and **non-reactive**.

Since we know that [the current data context is reactive](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata), hence can change without the template being re-rendered (which is what makes reactivity look all nice and smooth on Blaze), this `if` statement is written to check if the "real" current terms (which are stored in the *reactive* `Template.currentData()`) have changed compared to the "previous" terms we had **the last time the current template was rendered**. (stored in the *non-reactive* `template.data`)

To wrap it up, what this autorun does is:

1. Anytime the current data context changes...
2. Fetch the terms from said data context
3. Compare these terms to the ones stored in `template.data` when the template was rendered
4. If they differ, that means the terms have changed (duh): reset the post limit.

Comment: Why do we compare `newTerms` with `instance.data.terms`, instead of the previous value of `newTerms`? Now the post limit is reset when the terms have changed but the template isn't re-rendered, and then the next time the data context changes, even if the terms don't change this time, the post limit will be reset again. Is this what we want? Seems weird to me.

Comment: Also, do you mean that a template (UI) can be "updated" without being re-rendered? (Previously I thought every UI change was caused by a re-render.) If this is the case, a re-render still wouldn't trigger callbacks like `onCreated()` and `onRendered()`, right? So from the user's perspective, what's the logical difference between a re-render and an "update"? It seems like an implementation detail to me, and an optimization might cause something previously requiring a re-render to now only need an "update". Then why does an API like `template.data` depend on an implementation detail?

Comment: As for your first question: in my opinion this is a very legitimate concern you are pointing out. This bit of code is pretty recent, [it was authored on July 28th](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/commit/346f50d52bdcf6ec8f5a2c86587dd46d9fb83f80). I commented on the commit to get some feedback.

Comment: For your second question: yes, a template's DOM can be updated without the template re-rendering itself. It's basically what happens when, for example, you have an `{{#each}}` statement on your markup linked to a reactive source, and this source changes. So the `onRendered` and `onCreated` are triggered when the "static" part of the template's DOM (the parts that are not subject to reactivity, i.e. the parts outside of Spacebar conditionals) is rendered or re-rendered. If you want to have a hook for when reactive parts are re-rendered, [use a sub-template](http://goo.gl/fUIdmc).

Comment: I don't think `onCreated` and `onRendered` are triggered on re-renderings. According to the docs, they are triggered only once in the lifecycle of a template instance, during which there can be multiple re-renderings. In the docs under `Template.myTemplate.onRendered`: "In the body of a callback, `this` is a template instance object that is unique to this occurrence of the template and persists across re-renderings." I think I just don't know the definition of a "re-render". It's mentioned many times in the docs, but without a definition. I'm not even sure if it's used consistently.

Comment: The extract that you quoted is actually about the `this` object in the `onRendered` and `onCreated` callbacks. But yes you're right: ["Callbacks added with this method are called **once** when an instance of Template.myTemplate is rendered into DOM nodes and put into the document **for the first time**."](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) There have been lots of discussions on github and SO about whether the term "re-rendered" was appropriate. It sometimes seems like they mean the rendering of a *new* instance of the same template, such as when a new element appears in a list.

Comment: Yes, but from the text I quoted it seems like a single occurrence of a template can have multiple re-renderings, is this true? Or does a re-render always create a new instance of the template? If it's the latter, this would mean `template.data` never changes during the lifecycle of this template instance? In the docs `template.data` is defined as `The data context of this instance's latest invocation`. Alas, I have no idea what is an "invocation" of a template instance.

Comment: Yeah this doc is not clear. My take is that "across re-renderings" in that quote's context refers to data context reactive updates. As for "this instance's latest invocation", I am just guessing that it refers to invocation of each of the `onCreated`, `onRendered` and `onDestroyed` callbacks... whichever was triggered last at the t time this variable is being evaluated.

Comment: By the way, maybe it's obvious, but the reason we do all this is that if the user increments the limit a couple times by clicking "load more", and then switches away to a different "page" of Telescope (for example, going from one category to another), they would expect the limit to reset to the default (which wouldn't happen otherwise since the template's onCreated is not re-trigerring).

Answer (score 3):

Within ***post_list_controller.js*** in the `Template.onCreated()` there is a section with:

```
// initialize the reactive variables
  instance.terms = new ReactiveVar(instance.data.terms);
```

This reactive variable obtains it's terms value through:

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=template data=data}} // see posts_list_controller.html
```

Whenever you pass that template twice with a different set of data ([David Weldon - scoped-reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity)), that reactive variable will be set and will cause the autorun to run.

```
// this part will cause the autorun to run
var terms = Template.currentData().terms; // ⚡ reactive ⚡
```