# What exactly Template.currentData() in meteor is useful for?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am not able to understand exactly what Template.currentData() do. What I can understand from the documentation is I can use this to pass data from one template to another template but I can't find any example showing how to do that.

Also, I think we can achieve all the functionality provided by Template.currentData() from Session variable. Please let me know if I am wrong about this statement and why?

Comment: http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation suggests, The purpose of using `Template.currentData()` differs in the various utility like either helpers, events or callbacks of templates.

1. Inside an `onCreated`, `onRendered`, or `onDestroyed` callback, returns the data context of the template.
2. Inside an `event` handler, returns the data context of the template on which this event handler was defined.
3. Inside a `helper`, returns the data context of the DOM node where the helper was used.

> **NOTE**: `Template.currentData()` Establishes a reactive dependency on the result.

You can refer the already existing discussion on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505601/when-do-template-currentdata-and-template-data-differ-in-value?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You can [click here](https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-currentData) for more information